# Cycle in dependencies between targets 'MyApp' and 'MyLib'

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have included a new library in the project using CocoaPods and every time it builds on Azure DevOps agents, get following error:

> Cycle in dependencies between targets 'MyApp' and 'MyLib'; building
>   could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by
>   moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile Sources.

Cycle path: Pods-MyApp → MyLib → Pods-MyApp

I've tried `pod deintegrate` then `pod install` it did fix the issue, but each time I tried to build, gets the same error,
builds perfect locally but not on the build agent.